# In the following right $\Delta ABC$, $AC = BC = 1$ and $DEF$ is an arc of a circle with center $A$.

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles, area

> In the following right $\Delta ABC$, $AC = BC = 1$ and $DEF$ is an arc of a circle with center $A$. Suppose the shaded areas $BDE$ and $CEF$ are equal. Then $AD = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x}}.$ Find $x$ .

**What I Tried**: Here is a picture :-

[image]

No idea for this. I cannot understand how I can get the position of point $E$ given that the area of both the red sections are the same. I cannot think of any idea to get the areas either since they are formed from arc of the circle.

Can anyone give me a small idea of how to start this? Thank You.

**Edit**: So the hint from @Student1058 , I think I have actually solved the problem but getting stuck somewhere.

We see that the area of $\Delta ABC$ is same as the area of the sector $ADF$.

We have :- $$\rightarrow [\Delta ABC] = \frac{(1 * 1)}{2} = 0.5$$
Also we have the central angle of the sector to be $45^\circ$ as this is an isosceles right-angled triangle. 
So area of a sector given its radius and central angle would be :-
$$\rightarrow \frac{(r^2 * 45)}{2} = 0.5$$
$$\rightarrow r^2 = \frac{1}{45}$$
$$\rightarrow r = AD = \frac{1}{\sqrt{45}} = \frac{1}{3\sqrt{5}}$$

But the question says the answer should be of the form of $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x}}$ , where did I go wrong?

Comment: Note that the two red areas being equal actually implies that the areas of $\triangle ABC$ and sector $ADF$ are also equal. Then it should be easy.

Comment: Aah, that's interesting, didn't think about it .

Comment: @Student1058 I tried after what you said , but I am not getting my desired answer. Did I go wrong anywhere?

Comment: @Anonymous You should consider the angle in radians, i.e., $\frac\pi 4$...

Comment: @Anonymous, yes you must consider in radians. $AD=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$[\triangle ABC]=(ADF)$$

$$\frac{1\times1}{2}=\frac{\pi (\sqrt{x})^2 }{8}$$

$$x=\frac{4}{\pi}$$

Area of a sector with $\alpha$ is $\frac{{\pi} r^2\times \alpha }{360}$

Comment: So is $\frac{4}{\pi}$ the radius of the sector or it is the answer?

Comment: $AD=r=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x}}=\sqrt{x}$ then $x=\frac{4}{{\pi}}$ is the answer

Comment: $x=\frac{4}{{\pi}}$ but $AD=r=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}$

Comment: Oh alright got it .